# Which version of ADF to use when a trend is suspected?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a particular data set where there is strong seasonality, and possibly a trend or non-stationarity. The seasonal decomposition looks as follows:[image]

I am a bit confused as to what the order should be in which I perform my tests. First, I do believe I should perform an ADF test on the deseasoned data.
But then I don't know which version to use, the one that takes into account a trend, or the one that doesn't.

Could someone please explain this to me?